# How to disable the "table" tag behavior

Tags: html, html-table

If there is an overlapping join on different rows of the table, then the row may disappear:

```html
<table border="1" bordercolor="#999" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="2px" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
<div>R1C1:R2C1 (row 1)</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>R1C2 (row 1)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
<div>R2C2:R3C2 (row 2)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>R3C1 (row 3 should not be here)</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is unacceptable. May have to abandon the "table" tag. What to do?

Comment: What’s unacceptable is that you’re using rowspan incorrectly and expects the browser to magically fix the improperly formatted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you mean. But I've removed the rowspan's and added colspan's to the code. Colspan will span your cell over multiple columns/cells.

More info can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

```html
<table border="1" bordercolor="#999" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="2px" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div>R1C1:R2C1 (row 1)</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>R1C2 (row 1)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div>R2C2:R3C2 (row 2)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div>R3C1 (row 3)</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to concatenate cells in rows 1-2 and 2-3 in any way in any table

Comment: I've tried that now and it's indeed an issue. The table seems to merge the rows. I'll dive into it and try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've included two `td` elements on the first row of your table, but only one `td` element on the second and third rows of your table, which will break your table layout - the browser doesn't know which column the cell is supposed to span. Fix this and your table should work.

Comment: The problem still remains. Another example: `<table width="200" border="1" align="center" 
     cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr> 
     <td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#FBF0DB">Ячейка 1</td>
     <td>Ячейка 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td/>
     <td rowspan="2">Ячейка 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
     <td>Ячейка 4</td>
     <td/>
    </tr>
   </table>`

Comment: Now you have two cells that are the first in the row asking for a rowspan of 2, but there are only 3 rows in total when you need 4 (and there are two broken `</td>`s with no preceding `<td>`!). The way you've written this, the browser just can't do what you're asking (or, really, what you're asking doesn't make sense in the context). Take a look at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) for an intro to how `rowspan` works and a working example you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of problems:

**Table wrongly formatted** (make sure the number of `td` matches, even if they are empty)

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Styles wrongly applied** (apply them by using `<style>` or referencing a stylesheet)

```
    <table style="color:white;background-color:black;">
```

**Extra: Don't use so many divs**

While there isn't exactly a problem with using the divs you are using, using too many of them will usually lead to bad practices.

Comment: Thanks for the div tag. Even a properly formatted table gives the wrong result.

Comment: Can you edit your question, explaining clearly what output do you want please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS tricks to hide border of last column so that the table is aligned as per your requirement.

```css
table td.last { 
border-left: hidden;
border-top:hidden;
}
table td.last2 { 
border-left: hidden;
border-bottom:hidden
}
```

```html
<table border="1" bordercolor="#999" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="2px" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
<div>R1C1:R2C1 (row 1)</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<div>R1C2 (row 1)</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" style="border-right:hidden">
<div>R2C2:R3C2 (row 2)</div>
</td>
<td class="last2"><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>R3C1 (row 3 should not be here)</div>
</td>
<td class="last"><br></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```